# Python SQLite3 How to refer to loop in query

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLLite3 database containing a single table of stock prices, which looks like this:

```
   Ticker             DateTime   Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
0    ZUMZ  2011-11-01 00:00:00  21.65  23.24  20.74  22.84   558700
1    ZUMZ  2011-11-02 00:00:00  23.33  23.86  22.58  23.03   543200
2    ZUMZ  2011-11-03 00:00:00  23.28  23.74  21.82  22.67   492100
3    ZUMZ  2011-11-04 00:00:00  22.43  22.86  21.87  22.45   267320
```

I am trying to loop through a list of symbols and return the appropriate data.

I can return the correct results for one symbol in a list, like this:

```
tickers = ('AA',)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl_USELOC_02 WHERE Ticker=?', tickers)
data = cursor.fetchall()
df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
print df

        0                    1          2          3          4          5  \
0      AA  1951-06-11 00:00:00   0.675918   0.682062   0.675918   0.682062   
1      AA  1951-06-12 00:00:00   0.679605   0.686978   0.679605   0.683291   
2      AA  1951-06-13 00:00:00   0.682062   0.684520   0.680834   0.683291   
3      AA  1951-06-14 00:00:00   0.685749   0.700497   0.685749   0.700497   
4      AA  1951-06-15 00:00:00   0.705412   0.710328   0.705412   0.707870   
5      AA  1951-06-18 00:00:00   0.705412   0.710328   0.705412   0.707870
```

But, if I try to do the same with a loop, like this:

```
tickers = ['ZUMZ', 'AA']
for ticker in tickers:
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl_USELOC_02 WHERE Ticker=?', ticker)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
    print df
```

...I get an error message:
'ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.'

Can anybody tell me how I can run the query on the items in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make `ticker` a tuple:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl_USELOC_02 WHERE Ticker=?', (ticker,))
```

You could also make it a list:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl_USELOC_02 WHERE Ticker=?', [ticker])
```

Comment: And the '4 supplied' bit in the error message refers to the four characters in the string 'ZUMZ', because it's treating the argument as an iterable.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters -- thanks for adding the specific answer even though it was a duplicate. Apologies for the duplicate, I didn't find that answer when I was searching. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Cameron -- thanks for the additional info.